# Xamarin Forms - making webview go back

Tags: c#, android, ios, webview, xamarin.forms

Morning all,

I am working on a little crossplatform webview project in Xamarin.Forms. I have the webview working but I want to add in a toolbar which has a Back and Forward buttons.

I tried a number of different ways but nothing seems to be working particularly well. I tried to implement this feature by following this guys post [Navigation Toolbar](https://www.syntaxismyui.com/xamarin-forms-navigation-bar-buttons-recipe/)

I will attach my code below and if someone could give me a hand with this or a solution that would be great!

And if this question has already been answered previously by another user then I apologize.

**App.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace DisplayWebPage
{
    public class App : Application
    {
        public App()
        {
            // The root page of your application
            MainPage = new WebPage();
        }

        protected override void OnStart()
        {
            // Handle when your app starts
        }

        protected override void OnSleep()
        {
            // Handle when your app sleeps
        }

        protected override void OnResume()
        {
            // Handle when your app resumes
        }
    }
}
```

**WebPage.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection.Emit;
using System.Text;

using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace DisplayWebPage
{
    public class WebPage : ContentPage
    {
        public WebPage()
        {
            Content = new StackLayout
            {
                Children = {
                    new WebView
                    {
                        Source = "http://www.google.com"
                    }
                }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Looking forward to getting an answer to this as ive been stuck on it for quite awhile now.

Kind regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit your code like this.
First wrap your `MainPage` in a `NavigationPage` to make the toolbar visible.

It basically comes down to create a variable to be able to access your `WebView` easier.

Then create a button in you `ToolbarItems` collection which can trigger an event. And in that event you can call the already available `GoBack()` method on the `WebView`.

You probably want to check out the [Xamarin documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/user-interface/webview/#Navigation) on the `WebView`, it is probably a good idea to check if you *can* actually go back with the `CanGoBack` property.

Note that I have assigned a `BackIcon.png` you can replace it with `null` or your own icon of course.
Also the code hasn't been tested, this is just out of the top of my head so maybe there are missing some semi-colons or stuff.

**App.cs**

```
// ... other code

public App()
{
   // The root page of your application
   MainPage = new NavigationPage(new WebPage());
}
// ... other code
```

**WebPage.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection.Emit;
using System.Text;

using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace DisplayWebPage
{
    public class WebPage : ContentPage
    {
        private WebView _webView;

        public WebPage()
        {
           // Assign a WebView to a global variable
            _webView = new WebView
                    {
                        Source = "http://www.google.com",
                        HeightRequest="1000",
                       WidthRequest="1000" 
                    };

            // Create toolbar items here
            ToolbarItems.Add(new ToolbarItem("Back", "BackIcon.png", () => { _webview.GoBack(); }));

            Content = new StackLayout
            {
                Children = { _webView}
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have added in that code there and it still isnt going back to the previous page. Also Im testing on a Android emulator but the toolbar that I want on top of the screen isnt showing up at all?

Comment: So i got the toolbar working I think. I just added in 

`public App()
        {
            // The root page of your application
            MainPage = new NavigationPage(new WebPage());
        }` 

But now the WebView isnt showing up. Any ideas? I read somewhere that you can only have one item on each ContentPage, could this be the issue?

Comment: Try giving your `WebView` a `WidthRequest` and `HeightRequest`

Comment: So I have tested it a few times and it seems to work...every now and again. By that I mean, I have to have the emulator turned off then run the program then turn it back on and it works perfectly after that. I dont know if its just a problem with the emulator or what. I'll have to do a few more tests on my device later tonight. If you have ever come across something like this before please let me know :) I will keep you update later when I find out if its just an emulator issue or not.Thanks for helping!

Comment: If it has helped you to achieve the navigating back functionality please accept it as an answer :)

Answer (score 3):

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34313292/940098) by [Gerald Versluis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1506387/gerald-versluis) is great. Based on that, I would like to share how my code looks like after I tried to solve the following issues:

- Tried to implement the toolbar and webview in XAML (using VS2017)
- Hiding toolbar when front page is displayed (no need for back)
- Overriding the device back button

**App.xaml.cs**

```
// ... using, namespace etc

    public partial class App : Application
    {
        public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
        }
    }

// ...
```

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp"
             x:Class="MyApp.MainPage"
             NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False"
             Title="My App">

    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem Name="Back" Clicked="OnBack"></ToolbarItem>
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>

    <WebView x:Name="browser" Navigating="OnNavigating"></WebView>
</ContentPage>
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace MyApp
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        string Url;

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            browser.Source = Url = GetUrl();
        }

        void OnBack(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            browser.GoBack();
        }

        protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
        {
            if (browser.CanGoBack)
            {
                browser.GoBack();
                return true;
            }
            else return base.OnBackButtonPressed();
        }

        void OnNavigating(object sender, WebNavigatingEventArgs args)
        {
            // Checking if we are at the home page url
            // browser.CanGoBack does not seem to be working (not updating in time)
            NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, args.Url != Url);
        }

        string GetUrl()
        {
            // Possibly some mechanism to accomoddate for several locales
            return "...";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this, very helpful! All other solutions were missing a piece of the picture.

Answer (score 1):

Try following steps:
Add Navigated event in WebView object

```
 List<string> history = new List<string>();
 WebView myWebView = new WebView
 {
      Source = "http://www.google.com"
 };
myWebView.Navigated += WebViewPage_Navigated;
Children = myWebView;
```

Then define following function:

```
public void WebViewPage_Navigated(object sender, WebNavigatedEventArgs e)
{
    WebNavigationResult result = e.Result;            
    if(result.Equals(WebNavigationResult.Success)){
        currentUrl = e.Url;
       history.Add(currentUrl);
    }            
}
```

Now you can bind 'Forward' and 'Prev' element based on history list count and current element (if moved to back, then add to forward list). Hope this helps.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? The `WebView` has default `GoBack` and `GoForward` methods. See the Xamarin documentation here; https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/user-interface/webview/#Navigation

Comment: But the forms cannot goForward or goBack when user clicked fragment links.